# Compare values between 3 lists and add missing values from first list into the remaining 2 lists - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, list, linq

I need to prepare a chart wherein I'm required to show 3 lines.

One for showing new issues for a week, second for closed issues for a week and third for total accumulative open issues from first week to last week.

For this reason, I have prepared a query and was able to create 2 separate lists successfully - one list maintains the weekly count of new issues and second list maintains the weekly count of closed issues.

Here is the sample data for first list (one which maintains new issues) :

```
        [0]: { Week = {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
        [1]: { Week = {3/5/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
        [2]: { Week = {5/21/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 4 }
        [3]: { Week = {6/4/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 7 }
        [4]: { Week = {6/11/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 4 }
        [5]: { Week = {6/25/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 7 }
        [6]: { Week = {7/9/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 3 }
```

From the above data, I get the total count of open issues for a particular week.

**Note: For both these lists the Week values contain date which falls on Sunday.**
As I need the week to start on Monday while displaying data in the chart.

Similarly for sample data for second list (one which maintains closed issues) :

```
[0]: { Week = {12/13/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
[1]: { Week = {7/9/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 3 }
[2]: { Week = {6/18/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 2 }
[3]: { Week = {7/23/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 8 }
[4]: { Week = {10/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 6 }
[5]: { Week = {8/6/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 3 }
[6]: { Week = {9/17/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
```

From the above data, I get total count of closed issues for a particular week.

Here's the code for these lists :

```
var openIssuesList = getDetails.Where(x => x.ChangedTo == "Open").Select(x => new { Week = x.Date.AddDays(x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek).Date, Detail = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Week).Select(x => new { Week = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();


var closedIssuesList = getDetails.Where(x => x.ChangedTo == "Closed").Select(x => new { Week = x.Date.AddDays(x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek).Date, Detail = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Week).Select(x => new { Week = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

As I mentioned earlier, I need to prepare a weekly line chart using the data obtained from these lists. 
Now the final piece that remains is to fill in the missing week values into both of these lists using a third list which I have prepared.

I have prepared a list say **datesList** which contains all the dates (which fall on Sunday) between a specified date range.

Here's the sample data for this list :

```
[0]: {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[1]: {6/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[2]: {6/28/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[3]: {7/5/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[4]: {7/12/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[5]: {7/19/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[6]: {7/26/2015 12:00:00 AM}
//And so on ....
```

Explanation :

1. I need to compare the week values present in **datesList** with the week values of openIssuesList.
2. If a week value from **datesList** is also present in openIssuesList then do not add/alter such list value.
3. If a week value form **datesList** is not present in openIssuesList, then add such week value in openIssuesList list with it's Count value set to 0.
4. Repeat the same steps for closedIssuesList. (If this process can be done simultaneously avoiding repetation then please suggest)

So from the above provided sample data for 3 lists here's how the newly updated **openIssuesList** list should like : (showing only few records)

```
[0]: { Week = {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 } // Exisiting record hence no change for this record
[1]: { Week = {6/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 0 } // As this date was not existing initially it's been added with Count value set to 0
[2]: { Week = {6/28/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 0 } // As this date was not existing initially it's been added with Count value set to 0

//and so on....
```

The same logic applies for closedIssuesList.

So **datesList** is kind of 'Master List' and we need to compare the other lists with this list. If a week value present in **datesList** is missing from other lists then add this week value to other lists with the **Count** value being set to 0.

---

**EDIT** :

Initially in the lists **openIssuesList** & **closedIssuesList** I was not selecting IDs of these issues. Only the Week and Count of thee issues were being retrieved.

So to select these IDs I updated the logic for these both lists as follows :

```
 var openIssuesList = getDetails.Where(x => x.ChangedTo == "Open").Select(x => new { Week = x.Date.AddDays(x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek).Date, Detail = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Week).Select(x => new { Week = x.Key, Count = x.Count(), Issues = x.Select(y => y.Detail.IssueID).ToArray() }).ToList();                    

 var closedIssuesList = getDetails.Where(x => x.ChangedTo == "Closed").Select(x => new { Week = x.Date.AddDays(x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek).Date, Detail = x }).GroupBy(x => x.Week).Select(x => new { Week = x.Key, Count = x.Count(),Issues = x.Select(y => y.Detail.IssueID).ToArray() }).ToList();
```

Hence I just added this :

```
Issues = x.Select(y => y.Detail.IssueID).ToArray()
```

into my final Select clause and it'll help fetch the IssueID's as well (while initially we just fetched the count of these IssuesID's)

So far so good.

But now I want to include these IssuesID's into the **@stybl** provided solution as well.

So how should I modify my logic to accommodate IssueID's into **@stybl 's** solution.

Trying this would obviously give an error :

```
 openIssuesList.Concat(datesList.Where(date => !openIssuesList.Any(pair => pair.Week == date)).Select(date => new { Week = date, Count = 0, Issues = x.Select(y => y.Detail.IssueID).ToArray() });
```

How do I select the appropriate IssueID's for this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
openIssuesList.Concat(datesList.Where(date => !openIssuesList.Any(pair => pair.Week == date))
                               .Select(date => new { Week = date, Count = 0 });
```

What we do here is we get the inverse of the intersect of the two lists based on date. From that we select the anonymous object with the data, and finally append the resulting enumeration to `openIssuesList`.

Likewise for `closedIssuesList`:

```
closedIssuesList.Concat(datesList.Where(date => !closedIssuesList.Any(pair => pair.Week == date))
                                 .Select(date => new { Week = date, Count = 0 });
```

Comment: Can you help me in fetching IssuesID's as mentioned in the EDIT section of this question.